# How do I change a specific div style using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, show

the image represents the html code:

fullimage: https://i.stack.imgur.com/izqd6.png
and this is my jquery code:

```
$(".transaContentEdit").click(function(e) { 
   alert($(this).closest(".transe_row").find(".edit_transa").attr("class"));
   $(this).closest(".transe_row").find(".edit_transa").show();

});
```

the alert returns me undefined; The main idea is when i click on `.transaContentEdit`, i want to "show" the `.edit_transa` class. What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: *you can see the image, please zoom it with ctrl +* We prefer right click -> View Image instead :)

Comment: $(this).closest(".transe_row").nextAll(".edit_transa").show(); this can be a solution. but it "show" all of the class edit_transa classes. I have to mention that the .edit_transa is included in a loop

Comment: Why have you pasted a screenshot of the DOM (inadequately sized), rather than pasting the actual html as text?

Comment: then use: $(this).closest(".transe_row").nextAll(".edit_transa").first().show()

Comment: cus , it will show me an error that there are to much code and less explication texts

Comment: why this post is voted down? what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.transaContentEdit** is at the same level with **.edit_transa** so you can't use .find() because .find() is use just to find childs from an element. You can try something like this:

```
$(".transaContentEdit").click(function(e) {
     alert($(this).closest(".transe_row").parent().find(".edit_transa").attr("class"));
     $(this).closest(".transe_row").parent().find(".edit_transa").show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".transaContentEdit").click(function(e) { 
   $(this).parents(".transe_row").parent().find(".edit_transa").show();
});
```